# How to access multiple id elements in serenity-js

Tags: javascript, typescript, selenium, serenity-bdd, serenity-js

I have 5 links with the same name and id and linktext. I am using serenity-js. how can I access the 4th link

page.ts has

```
static link = Target.the('click the 4th link').located(by.linktext('link'));
```

Comment: Ids _must_ be unique

Comment: Let us say ids are not unique or id is same or there is no id. Are you telling me serenity-js cannot handle controls with same id ?

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML including the _parent node_ of the _child nodes_ containing the _links_

Comment: ok :-) Please find the HTML with no parent nor child nodes. <a>link</a><a>link</a><a>link</a> <a>link</a> <a>link</a> , I am looking forward for an equilavent of element.all(by.linktext('link')); for serenity-js. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that can help anyone but Target finds all elements with specified selector, so what you can do in Java (not sure about javascript though) is you can map the result to:

`List<WebElement> links = link.resolveAllFor(actor);`

and then access by index links.get(x)